# checkbox returns "on" value after it is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, checkbox

I'm following a tutorial where you make a checkbox that enables a disabled button and when you uncheck the box, the button becomes disabled again. The problem is that when I uncheck the box, it seems like the checkbox still in an "on" state because the button is not disabled. The code works in Chrome but not in Firefox 3.6.

Here is my code:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" id="agree" >I agree</p>
<input id="continue" type="button" value="continue" disabled='true'>


<script>
        $('#agree').change(function(){
       var state = $(this).attr('value');
        if(state == 'on'){
        $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else if(state == ''){
            $('#continue').attr('disabled', 'false');
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The "disabled" attribute does *not* take the values `"true"` or `"false"`. It takes the values `"disabled"` (alternatively `""`) or must be removed.

Comment: ...Though if you have a direct reference to the DOM element you can say `el.disabled = true; // or false`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a checkbox's check value doesn't change with `.val()` you should be using `.is('checked')` like so:

```
$('#agree').change(function() {
    var state = $(this).is(':checked'); //state = true/false depending on state
    if (state) { //if true
        $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled'); //remove disabled
    } else { //else (false)
        $('#continue').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //add disabled (you shouldn't set it to 'false' as it WILL be disabled and it'll confuse you.
    }
});
```

Here's an **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/q9Hag/)** to see my points.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6, you also could use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to access the DOM object property directly and actually set `disabled` to `true` or `false` this way.

Comment: Perhaps Chrome's javascript engine is different and understand the element's value as whether it is checked or not, I don't know. However, even if it does work in Chrome, this is not the correct solution, what I posted is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#agree').change(function() {
    if($("#agree").is(":checked"))
        $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
    else
        $('#continue').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TGQZs/1/

Comment: Values like `"true"` or `"false"` are *invalid* for the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: @Tomalak - jQuery handles those in the background, although you can use `'false'`, you're right, it should be `false`.

Comment: My point is more that it works fine with `false` only in jQuery which leads people to believing it would be proper HTML as well (as you can see in the question). I *might* be a bit pedantic here, but I think valid HTML values should go to `attr()`, and booleans can go to `prop()`, at least on a website like this. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak s/booleans/state values

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$(function() {
    $('#agree').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#continue').attr('disabled', false);
        else $('#continue').attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

LINK : http://jsfiddle.net/Mmm4h/